# Does Incineroar's ability, Strong Cheer, affect attacks that normally deal no damage?

Tags: pokemon

I have a benched **Incineroar** (Unbroken Bonds 29) with **Strong Cheer** ability.

> **Strong Cheer**
>   Your Pokémon's attacks do 30 more damage to your opponent's Active Pokémon *(before applying Weakness and Resistance)*. You can't apply more than 1 Strong Cheer Ability at a time.

If I have an active **Cosmog** (Sun & Moon 64) with **Dust Gathering** attack, does it do 30 damage? I assume **Strong Cheer** would make it do 30 damage, but I have been unable to find clarification online.

> [C] **Dust Gathering**
>   Draw a card.

[image: Incineroar UNB 29] [image: Cosmog SUM 64]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using **Dust Gathering** with a benched **Incineroar** with **Strong Cheer** ability does no damage.

From the official [Rulings Compendium BW](https://compendium.pokegym.net/compendium-bw.html#c3):

> An attack has to do "some" damage before an effect can add "more" damage to it. (Jan 31, 2008 PUI Rules Team)

Comment: This is generally true in the game - for example, if something makes a card have "no retreat cost", nothing can add to the retreat cost, but if the retreat cost is reduced to 0 then it can.

Comment: thanks for the link to the rules compendium -- I'd looked for something like that, but was unable to find it.

Comment: Does this rule still hold for something like poisoning? This does no damage until Pokémon checkup, which is after the attack.

Comment: Poison does no damage, it puts damage counters which is a different thing :-)